# Push Notification in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to implement Toast notification in my Windows Phone 7.1 app.Using this code i'm sending the notification from server to windows phone:

```
  string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                  "<wp:Toast>" +
                     "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                     "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                     "<wp:Text3>" + TextBoxMessage.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text3>" +
                     "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" +
                "</wp:Toast> " +
            "</wp:Notification>";
```

I want to save the value which is stored in Text1,Text2 and Text3  in local database of windows phone but i don't know how should i approach for this.
Please tell me how can i store the value in local database for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can't save push notification parameters in the local storage. After push notification is received a secondary or a main tile of your app will be updated automatically by Windows Phone platform. But you can choose an another approach - pass required parameters with `wp:Param` and load all necessary data after user is navigated to a `Page` from the tile.

```
  string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                  "<wp:Toast>" +
                     "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                     "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                     "<wp:Text3>" + TextBoxMessage.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text3>" +
                     "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?DataId=123&UserId=12</wp:Param>" +
                "</wp:Toast> " +
            "</wp:Notification>";
```